# Entity Framework Migration created extra column in table

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have following business objects :

```
    public class CreatedCompositeEntity : Entity, IEntity, IModified, ICreated, IIsActive
    {
        public CreatedCompositeEntity()
        {
            IsActive = true;
        }
        [Required, Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public Nullable<DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
    public class HeadCollectionTypeBO : CreatedCompositeEntity
    {
                public HeadCollectionTypeBO()
                {
                    IsActive = true;
                }

                public string CollectionType { get; set; }
    }
    public class HeadBO : CreatedCompositeEntity
    {
            public HeadBO()
            {
                IsActive = true;
            }

            public string HeadName { get; set; }


            public int VenueId { get; set; }
            public virtual VenueBO Venue { get; set; }

            public int CollectionTypeId { get; set; }
            public virtual HeadCollectionTypeBO CollectionType { get; set; }
     }
```

After migration is executed, there is extra column has been added in (m_head)HeadBO as CollectionType_Id and CollectionType_CreatedBy. I am very new in Entity Framework. Kindly suggest me solution.

Comment: This is because you have created composite PK in your base class `{ Id, CreatedBy }`. Which makes no any sense because the `Id` (identity) should be unique. And the effect is that now other tables cannot simply refer to it by `Id` (like your `CollectionTypeId`), so EF creates the two additional fields in question ":for you".

Comment: i think at `class HeadBO` u reference `class HeadCollectionTypeBO`, so entity will understand u need create id of HeadCollectionTypeBO table (in that case table have composite key - Id and CreateBy). if you dont want to create it, u need put attribute like this `[NotMapped] public virtual HeadCollectionTypeBO CollectionType { get; set; }`. hope help

Comment: @Ivan stoev Actually I have online/offline scenario. So there are many user may enter same data in HEADBO thats why I have created Composite key.

Comment: Then `Id` should not be identity column. And the FK's should also be composite.

Comment: @Ivan stoev Here I have ID as identity and createdBy is not an Identity. can you please give me sample code...

Comment: It's not really EF topic, but database design. The identity column is auto generated by database when you insert new record, and is unique, so adding second column to already unique column does not make the key more unique (because it's already unique). I have no idea what you code does and what do you mean by online/offline scenario in order to give you a concrete advice. All I'm saying is that you ether remove `CreatedBy` from the PK (by removing `[Key]` and `Column(Order = 1)` annotations) and keep the `HeadBO` as it is now, or configure `HeadBO` FK to be composite as well.

Comment: @ Hua Trung I have applied your suggestion and extra columns are removed. But also What I need is that my CollectionType should get data from table on the basis of CollectionType ID.